# Problem with bibliography sorting (name repeated)

Tags: bibliographies, sorting, historische-zeitschrift

I have a problem with only one entry in biography. It is the same author but his work instead of being grouped under one name gets separate sorting.

It looks like this:

[image: Sorting]

I checked spelling and all names have the same spelling. Does anyone know why it is sorted this way?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{footnote}{section}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{grillmeier1992,
    Address = {Innsbruck/{\,}Wien},
    Author = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Booktitle = {Chalcedon und die Folgen: Festschrift 60. Geburtstag von Bischof Mesrob K. Krikorian},
    Call-Number = {TH: Dc 1.100},
    Date-Added = {2016-02-03 12:53:52 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-12-08 08:27:55 +0000},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Pages = {215-242},
    Publisher = {Tyrolia Verlag},
    Title = {Die Rezeption des Konzils von Chalzedon durch die r{\"o}misch-katholische Kirche},
    Year = {1992}}
@book{grillmeier1989,
    Address = {Freiburg/{\,}Basel/{\,}Wien},
    Author = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Call-Number = {TH: Dq1.175 2/3},
    Date-Added = {2014-07-24 15:28:40 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-12-08 08:50:39 +0000},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Publisher = {Herder},
    Title = {Jesus der Christus im Glauben der Kirche},
    Volume = {2: Die Kirche von Konstantinopel im 6. Jahrhundert},
    Year = {1989}}
@incollection{engberding1953,
    Address = {W{\"u}rzburg},
    Author = {Hieronymus Engberding},
    Booktitle = {Das Konzil von Chalkedon: Geschichte und Gegenwart},
    Call-Number = {TH: Ef VI 14/2},
    Date-Added = {2013-11-01 13:12:17 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-11-01 13:17:37 +0000},
    Editor = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Number = {II},
    Pages = {697-733},
    Publisher = {Echter Verlag},
    Shortauthor = {Engberding},
    Shorttitle = {Das chalkedonische Christusbild},
    Title = {Das chalkedonische Christusbild und die Liturgien der monophysitischen Kirchengemeinschaften},
    Year = {1953}}
@incollection{grillmeier1981,
    Address = {Innsbruck/{\,}Wien},
    Author = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Booktitle = {Das gemeinsame Credo: 1600 Jahre seit dem Konzil von Konstantinopel},
    Call-Number = {TH: Dc1.617},
    Date-Added = {2013-08-27 16:30:48 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-08-19 11:11:47 +0000},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Pages = {48-54},
    Publisher = {Tyrolia Verlag},
    Title = {Das nizaeno-konstantinopolitanische Glaubensbekenntnis},
    Year = {1981}}
@book{grillmeier1951-54,
    Address = {W{\"u}rzburg},
    Call-Number = {TH: Ef VI 14/1-3},
    Date-Added = {2013-08-23 09:57:03 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-12-08 08:06:02 +0000},
    Editor = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Keywords = {nocite},
    Number = {I-III},
    Publisher = {Echter Verlag},
    Title = {Das Konzil von Chalkedon: Geschichte und Gegenwart},
    Year = {1951-54}}
@book{grillmeier1954,
    Address = {W{\"u}rzburg},
    Call-Number = {TH: Ef VI 14/3},
    Date-Added = {2012-02-21 15:06:42 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2017-12-08 08:05:59 +0000},
    Editor = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Number = {III},
    Publisher = {Echter Verlag},
    Title = {Das Konzil von Chalkedon: Geschichte und Gegenwart},
    Year = {1954}}
@book{grillmeier1975,
    Address = {Freiburg/{\,}Basel/{\,}Wien},
    Author = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Call-Number = {TH: Ef III 97},
    Date-Added = {2010-05-27 17:05:21 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2010-10-18 14:18:00 +0200},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Publisher = {Herder},
    Title = {Mit ihm und in ihm: Christologische Forschungen und Perspektiven},
    Year = {1975}}
@book{grillmeier1951,
    Address = {W{\"u}rzburg},
    Call-Number = {TH: Ef VI 14/1},
    Date-Added = {2010-04-21 10:36:53 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2017-12-08 08:06:05 +0000},
    Editor = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Number = {I},
    Publisher = {Echter Verlag},
    Title = {Das Konzil von Chalkedon: Geschichte und Gegenwart},
    Year = {1951}}
@book{grillmeier1990,
    Address = {Freiburg/{\,}Basel/{\,}Wien},
    Author = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Call-Number = {TH: Dq1.175 1/3},
    Date-Added = {2010-03-12 14:00:25 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2017-12-08 08:50:34 +0000},
    Edition = {3},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Publisher = {Herder},
    Title = {Jesus der Christus im Glauben der Kirche},
    Volume = {1: Von der Apostolischen Zeit bis zum Konzil von Chalcedon (451)},
    Year = {1990}}
@book{betz1979,
    Address = {Freiburg/{\,}Basel/{\,}Wien},
    Author = {Johannes Betz},
    Call-Number = {TH: Dd 1.040/4,4a.b},
    Date-Added = {2009-01-24 14:09:59 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2014-08-18 07:47:01 +0000},
    Editor = {Michael Schmaus and Alois Grillmeier and Leo Schefffczyk and Michael Seybold},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Number = {4},
    Publisher = {Herder},
    Series = {Handbuch der Dogmengeschichte},
    Title = {Eucharistie in der Schrift und Patristik},
    Year = {1979}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - FIXING "( HRSG.)" TO " (HRSG.)"%
%
\makeatletter%
\renewbibmacro*{editorstrg}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{editor}>1\OR\ifandothers{editor}}%
    {\bibstring[\mkbibparens]{editors}}%
    {\bibstring[\mkbibparens]{editor}}}%
\makeatother%
%
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - PUBLISHER IN BIBLIOGRAPHY NOT OMMITED%
%
\makeatletter%
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+year}{%
  \printlist{location}:%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printlist{publisher}\addcomma%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit}%
\makeatother%
%
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - NO PAGES IN INCOLLECTION FOOTNOTES BUT PAGES IN BIBLIOGRAPHY%
%
\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
    \printfield{chapter}%
    \newunit}%
% 
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - NO PAGES IN ARTICLE FOOTNOTES BUT PAGES IN BIBLIOGRAPHY%
%
\newbibmacro*{onlypages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \newunit}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
%     \newunit\newblock
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
%     \newunit\newblock
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{note}%
%     \newunit\newblock
  \setunit*{\newunitpunct}%
\usebibmacro{onlypages}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
  \AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
  \DeclareNameAlias{upshape}{family-given}
  \renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
}
%
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - ADDING ZITIERT AUF INSTEAD OF SIEHE S. IN BIBLIOGRAPHY
%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  backrefpage  = {Zitiert auf S\adddot},
  backrefpages = {Zitiert auf S\adddot},
}
%
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{grillmeier1992}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 22]{grillmeier1989}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{engberding1953}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{grillmeier1990}
\pagebreak
\section{Second section}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{grillmeier1981}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{grillmeier1951-54}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 12]{grillmeier1954}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{betz1979}
\pagebreak
\section{Third section}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 11]{grillmeier1975}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{grillmeier1990}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 12]{grillmeier1951}
\pagebreak
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with sorting per se.

The problem here is that the macro  `editorincoll` clears `\bbx@lasthash`, which `biblatex` needs to compare the author/editor to the last one to decide whether or not to use print a dash.

I think the `\global\undef\bbx@lasthash` was accidentally copied to `editorincoll`. It should have no business changing `\bbx@lasthash`.

With

```
\renewbibmacro*{editorincoll}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifuseeditor\AND\NOT\ifnameundef{editor}}
    {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{author}{editor}\AND
                 \NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames[upshape]{editor}\addspace
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}
```

you get all dashes for Grillmeier.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! This almost solved the problem. Now all are sorted under name of Grillmeier but next to his name there is also editor tag (Hrsg) which shouldn't be there. It should only be before those entries where he is editor or if that is too complicated it should be removed completely

Comment: @eklisiarh When I add the code from my answer to your MWE I get to see '(Hrsg.)' exactly three times for Grillmeier: namely for the first three `@book`s (which I believe should be `@collection`s if he is an editor, but nevermind). This is consistent with the screenshot from your question where there are three '(Hrsg.)'s as well. If you see something different, please open a new question with a new MWE.

Comment: @eklisiarh Did you manage to reproduce the '(Hrsg.)' problem? Or is it solved?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I marked it as solved here but I am still not completely happy with the solution because this puts (Hrsg.) after the name `Grillmeier, Alois (Hrsg.):`.This is ok because in the first book he is editor but this makes impression that all of the books listed are made of him as editor. More logically would be if his name was followed by the colon, empty space and than editor tag like this:  `Grillmeier, Alois: (Hrsg.)` but I suspect that would be hard to implement.

Comment: @eklisiarh Mhhh, but the '(Hrsg.)' is repeated in the other lines if he is indeed the editor, so it should be fairly clear that it is not implied he is editor for all the dashed works. If you insist on your highly unusual solution (I have never seen it before) you can certainly ask a new question about that, maybe it can be implemented. (I'm quite sure it can be implemented, the question is whether or not it takes a lot of code and if it is worth the hassle.)

Comment: I am not sure you understand what I mean. I will make new question for that just so you can see what I am saying about and if it is too much work I will just edit the PDF manually later to have this. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406761/same-person-as-author-and-editor-sorting-problem

Answer (score 4):

For the entry `grillmeier1992`, it looks like you're either missing the `editor` field or are using the incorrect entry type.

- For entries of type `@incollection`, the `editor` field is *required*. The editors of the piece were Kirchschäger and Stirnemann, right? Hence, just add the line

  ```
  editor = "R. Kirchschäger and A. Stirnemann",
  ```

  to the entry `grillmeier1992`.
- Alternatively, if you do *not* want to list the editors, you should change the entry type to `@inbook`.

Whichever adjustment you choose, the sorting issue will disappear.

Comment: Thank you, this helped but it only solved part of the problem. I still have Grillmeier twice in the bibliography. First time as author, second time as editor. Should I ask separate question for this?

Comment: @eklisiarh - I think that's an issue to raise with the maintainer(s) of the `historische-zeitschrift` biblatex style. (FWIW, I agree with you that having separate groups for "Grillmeier (Hrsg)" and "Grillmeyer" is less than optimal.)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I edited my question to include `historische-zetischrift` tag. Maybe the author is also here in forum.