# Same person as author and editor sorting problem

Tags: biblatex, editors, sorting, author

I have a problem that if I have same person as author and editor for several books Biblatex connects editor tag with his name and not with particular book.

Here is what I mean:

[image]

1. The first book that is listed here is the oldest one (that's OK)
2. Grillmeier is the editor of this first book so before the name of this book it should be written (Hrsg.) just like with all other books where he is editor.

The problem is:

**This (Hrsg.) should not come before colons but after them! **

It should not be:

> Grillmeier, Alois (Hrsg.):

but it should be:

> Grillmeier, Alois: (Hrsg.):

This way one gets the impression that Grillmeier is listed here only as editor, which is not the case because for the entries 4-5 and also in last entry he is author.

So I need to find a way to add colon behind the authors name and in front of (Hrsg.).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{footnote}{section}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{grillmeier1992,
    Address = {Innsbruck and Wien},
    Author = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Booktitle = {Chalcedon und die Folgen: Festschrift 60. Geburtstag von Bischof Mesrob K. Krikorian},
    Call-Number = {TH: Dc 1.100},
    Date-Added = {2016-02-03 12:53:52 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-12-08 13:49:43 +0000},
    Editor = {Rudolf Kirchschl{\"a}ger and Alfred Stirnemann},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Pages = {215-242},
    Publisher = {Tyrolia Verlag},
    Title = {Die Rezeption des Konzils von Chalzedon durch die r{\"o}misch-katholische Kirche},
    Year = {1992}}
@book{grillmeier1989,
    Address = {Freiburg and Basel and Wien},
    Call-Number = {TH: Dq1.175 2/3},
    Date-Added = {2014-07-24 15:28:40 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-12-16 15:00:12 +0000},
    Editor = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Publisher = {Herder},
    Title = {Jesus der Christus im Glauben der Kirche},
    Volume = {2: Die Kirche von Konstantinopel im 6. Jahrhundert},
    Year = {1989}}
@incollection{engberding1953,
    Address = {W{\"u}rzburg},
    Author = {Hieronymus Engberding},
    Booktitle = {Das Konzil von Chalkedon: Geschichte und Gegenwart},
    Call-Number = {TH: Ef VI 14/2},
    Date-Added = {2013-11-01 13:12:17 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-11-01 13:17:37 +0000},
    Editor = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Number = {II},
    Pages = {697-733},
    Publisher = {Echter Verlag},
    Shortauthor = {Engberding},
    Shorttitle = {Das chalkedonische Christusbild},
    Title = {Das chalkedonische Christusbild und die Liturgien der monophysitischen Kirchengemeinschaften},
    Year = {1953}}
@incollection{grillmeier1981,
    Address = {Innsbruck and Wien},
    Author = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Booktitle = {Das gemeinsame Credo: 1600 Jahre seit dem Konzil von Konstantinopel},
    Call-Number = {TH: Dc1.617},
    Date-Added = {2013-08-27 16:30:48 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-12-16 15:01:08 +0000},
    Editor = {Theodor Piffl-Percevic},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Pages = {48-54},
    Publisher = {Tyrolia Verlag},
    Title = {Das nizaeno-konstantinopolitanische Glaubensbekenntnis},
    Year = {1981}}
@book{grillmeier1951-54,
    Address = {W{\"u}rzburg},
    Call-Number = {TH: Ef VI 14/1-3},
    Date-Added = {2013-08-23 09:57:03 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-12-08 08:06:02 +0000},
    Editor = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Keywords = {nocite},
    Number = {I-III},
    Publisher = {Echter Verlag},
    Title = {Das Konzil von Chalkedon: Geschichte und Gegenwart},
    Year = {1951-54}}
@book{grillmeier1954,
    Address = {W{\"u}rzburg},
    Call-Number = {TH: Ef VI 14/3},
    Date-Added = {2012-02-21 15:06:42 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2017-12-08 08:05:59 +0000},
    Editor = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Number = {III},
    Publisher = {Echter Verlag},
    Title = {Das Konzil von Chalkedon: Geschichte und Gegenwart},
    Year = {1954}}
@book{grillmeier1975,
    Address = {Freiburg/{\,}Basel/{\,}Wien},
    Author = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Call-Number = {TH: Ef III 97},
    Date-Added = {2010-05-27 17:05:21 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2010-10-18 14:18:00 +0200},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Publisher = {Herder},
    Title = {Mit ihm und in ihm: Christologische Forschungen und Perspektiven},
    Year = {1975}}
@book{grillmeier1951,
    Address = {W{\"u}rzburg},
    Call-Number = {TH: Ef VI 14/1},
    Date-Added = {2010-04-21 10:36:53 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2017-12-08 08:06:05 +0000},
    Editor = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Number = {I},
    Publisher = {Echter Verlag},
    Title = {Das Konzil von Chalkedon: Geschichte und Gegenwart},
    Year = {1951}}
@book{grillmeier1990,
    Address = {Freiburg and Basel and Wien},
    Call-Number = {TH: Dq1.175 1/3},
    Date-Added = {2010-03-12 14:00:25 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2017-12-16 15:00:07 +0000},
    Edition = {3},
    Editor = {Alois Grillmeier},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Publisher = {Herder},
    Title = {Jesus der Christus im Glauben der Kirche},
    Volume = {1: Von der Apostolischen Zeit bis zum Konzil von Chalcedon (451)},
    Year = {1990}}
@book{betz1979,
    Address = {Freiburg/{\,}Basel/{\,}Wien},
    Author = {Johannes Betz},
    Call-Number = {TH: Dd 1.040/4,4a.b},
    Date-Added = {2009-01-24 14:09:59 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2014-08-18 07:47:01 +0000},
    Editor = {Michael Schmaus and Alois Grillmeier and Leo Schefffczyk and Michael Seybold},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Number = {4},
    Publisher = {Herder},
    Series = {Handbuch der Dogmengeschichte},
    Title = {Eucharistie in der Schrift und Patristik},
    Year = {1979}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - FIXING "( HRSG.)" TO " (HRSG.)"%
%
\makeatletter%
\renewbibmacro*{editorstrg}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{editor}>1\OR\ifandothers{editor}}%
    {\bibstring[\mkbibparens]{editors}}%
    {\bibstring[\mkbibparens]{editor}}}%
\makeatother%
%
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - PUBLISHER IN BIBLIOGRAPHY NOT OMMITED%
%
\makeatletter%
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+year}{%
  \printlist{location}:%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printlist{publisher}\addcomma%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit}%
\makeatother%
%
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - NO PAGES IN INCOLLECTION FOOTNOTES BUT PAGES IN BIBLIOGRAPHY%
%
\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
    \printfield{chapter}%
    \newunit}%
% 
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - NO PAGES IN ARTICLE FOOTNOTES BUT PAGES IN BIBLIOGRAPHY%
%
\newbibmacro*{onlypages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \newunit}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
%     \newunit\newblock
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
%     \newunit\newblock
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{note}%
%     \newunit\newblock
  \setunit*{\newunitpunct}%
\usebibmacro{onlypages}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
  \AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
  \DeclareNameAlias{upshape}{family-given}
  \renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
}
%
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - ADDING ZITIERT AUF INSTEAD OF SIEHE S. IN BIBLIOGRAPHY
%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  backrefpage  = {Zitiert auf S\adddot},
  backrefpages = {Zitiert auf S\adddot},
}
%
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{grillmeier1992}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 22]{grillmeier1989}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{engberding1953}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{grillmeier1990}
\pagebreak
\section{Second section}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{grillmeier1981}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{grillmeier1951-54}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 12]{grillmeier1954}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{betz1979}
\pagebreak
\section{Third section}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 11]{grillmeier1975}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{grillmeier1990}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 12]{grillmeier1951}
\pagebreak
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: If this is too complicated please don't waste too much of your time with this. I mainly added this because I was asked to do so in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405159/problem-with-bibliography-sorting-name-repeated/405359?noredirect=1#comment1014097_405359

Comment: I agree with @moewe that is quite clear where Grillmeier is author and where editor and imho a second colon simply looks odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you want is very unusual. And even though there is a possibility that people might erroneously think that Grillmeier is the editor of a work he is actually the author of with the default output shown in your question I am not convinced the output here is much clearer.

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\addcolon\space}% <- ORIGINAL: \addcomma\space
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother
```

The only change needed was `\setunit{\addcolon\space}` instead of `\setunit{\addspace}`.

Comment: Thanks I really didn't expect you to invest your time in this so I am even more grateful you did. What I will do is to present both options to the publisher and let them decide. Alternative that just came to my mind is to put dash there or to break the line. I will just give them all options and they will tell me what they want. It's good to have the solution ready so again: Thank you!

Comment: @eklisiarh You might not want to give them all the ideas at once. I haven't tested, but I think it a bit more involved to break the line properly there.

Comment: Yes but please do not invest any more time in this. If they decide to go with it I will ask again or something. Also I think I am almost done with the publishing preparation so I wish to thank you for all of the help you provided here. I would not make it without your help (and the help of some other people here on StackExchange)!